# Discord.NET Adding Reactions to a SocketMessage

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am using Discord.NET version 1.0.2 to clear things up

I have a MessageReceived Task in my Discord Bot application:

```
private async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
```

This task, as can already be deducted, runs every time a message is received in Discord to this bot. I am trying to figure out how to add a reaction to a message that the bot has received, however. Under `SocketMessage` there are no methods to add reactions to the message received. I looked online and found that `RestUserMessage` contains the method `AddReactionAsync(IEmote, RequestOptions)`. I then casted `Socket Message` to a `RestUserMessage` as so

```
var rMessage = (RestUserMessage) await message.Channel.GetMessageAsync(message.Id);
```

Running the `AddReactionAsync` method under my variable `rMessage` for `RestUserMessage` works, but the parameters are not taken correctly as I can perceive from my reading online and the documentation.

`IEmote` appears to be a string, but a string does not fulfill this parameter, saying that there is no conversion from a `String` to an `IEmote`. I tried casting this `String` to an `IEmote` but that did not work.

The `RequestOptions` variable seems to fulfill the parameter perfectly fine as a `new RequestOptions()`.

My full code for this is:

```
private async Task MessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
{
    var rMessage = (RestUserMessage) await message.Channel.GetMessageAsync(message.Id);
    rMessage.AddReactionAsync(???, new RequestOptions());
}
```

How do I fulfill this `IEmote` parameter correctly and or how do I define an `IEmote` variable. Also, is defining a `new RequestOptions()` variable the correct thing to fulfill this parameter as well. Is this also the correct way to add reactions to a message through Discord.NET and if not what is?

The research I have done:

```
https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/490
https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Rest.RestUserMessage.html
https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.IEmote.html
https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.RequestOptions.html
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you head over to [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/), and grab the unicode version as shown below : 
[image]

After that is copied, you have to create a new `Emoji` object, like so :

```
var YourEmoji = new Emoji("");
```

You can then add a reaction to the desired message, I'm going to use `Context.Message` :

```
Context.Message.AddReactionAsync(YourEmoji);
```

Comment: This only works for emojis which consist of a single unicode code point.

Answer (score 2):

Unknown's solution works for regular emotes, but won't work for guild-specific emotes.

This is the solution I came up with:

```
SocketGuild guild = ((SocketGuildChannel) message.Channel).Guild;
IEmote emote = guild.Emotes.First(e => e.Name == "my-custom-emote");
message.AddReactionAsync(emote);
```

Comment: If you're doing this from a command, it may be cleaner to use `var guild = Context.Guild;`

Answer (score 1):

You already found the way to adding the emoji, but I'll follow up with an additional way of adding a guild emoji to a message. You'd need the raw string of the emoji in this case. Don't confuse it with Emoji, `Emoji` represents an Unicode emoji, but `Emote` is from Discord.Net and stands for a custom emoji. The `AddReactionAsync` method accepts both objects thanks to the `IEmote` interface.

```
Emote emote = Emote.Parse("<:craig_cat:603083214281506817>")
```

In this case, we're creating an Emote object with the emoji called craig_cat and the provided ID.
In order to get the raw string to parse, in your Discord client, simply send the emoji (:craig_cat:), but with a backslash (`\`) before it.

Note, in case of an animated emoji, it will look like the following:

```
Emote emote = Emote.Parse("<a:running:703588456198307900>")
```

There has to be an `a` before the punctuation mark to identify it as an animated emoji.

In both cases, you can add it to the message by these examples:

```
Context.Message.AddReactionAsync(emote); //Adds the reaction to the user's message that triggered the task (works only in a command)
```

Most of the other interfaces/objects also support this method, casting would help though.

You can also use this raw format at any time to include the emoji in a message.